# Running variable is NaN, but debugging variable isn't NaN. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux-thunk

Why eventFace.order is NaN running and eventFace.order isn't NaN Debugging?
Error: 
[image: error_running]

```
let update = true;
const farAway = new Date(GetToday(500)).getTime();

for (const eventFace of facebookEvents) {
  update = true;
  for (const eventFire of firebaseEvents) {
     if (eventFace.id === eventFire.id) {
       update = false;
     }
  }

  if (update) {
    const eventDate = new Date(FormatDate(eventFace.start_time)).getTime();
    eventFace.order = farAway - eventDate;
    firebase.database().ref().child('events').push(eventFace);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you reviewed all eventFace objects? It seems that this piece of code `new Date(FormatDate(eventFace.start_time)).getTime()` is generating `NaN` if that's correct then that's why you are receiving `NaN` in `eventFace.order`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using React Native, you’re going to be running your JavaScript code in two environments:

On iOS simulators and devices, Android emulators and devices React Native uses JavaScriptCore which is the JavaScript engine that powers Safari. On iOS JSC doesn’t use JIT due to the absence of writable executable memory in iOS apps

When using Chrome debugging, it runs all the JavaScript code within Chrome itself and communicates with native code via WebSocket. So you are using V8. So , it’s better to use alternatives like [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) instead of Date object.Like

```
moment(FormatDate(eventFace.start_time), "MM-DD-YYYY Z").valueOf()
```

Note: FormatDate now should convert date to moment format  "MM-DD-YYYY Z"

You can check out below article for more information.

https://medium.com/@suyogkrazz/you-should-not-always-rely-on-remote-debugging-react-native-787a850c7ad8